# Collecting variable value changes and execution trace in Java

Tags: java, logging, execution

I'm relatively new to Java. Recently, I've been attempting to run test cases on existing projects. I'm aware that debugging tools, like those in Eclipse, allow me to step through test cases and monitor variable values at each step.

However, as the projects grow more intricate and the number of test cases rise, manually stepping through each one and noting down all the details becomes cumbersome. Is there a more efficient method to gather the code's execution sequence (I think it is also called execution trace) and the variable value changes during each statement's execution? (For example, is there a tool that can automatically produce log files containing this information?) Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Most people use automated tests, e.g. with [JUnit](https://junit.org) (at least for the bulk of their testing). In an automated test, the test is code (not a script that someone has to manually follow), and it includes one or more assertions that check that variables have expected values. Needing to know about the trace is a brittle way of tying test and code under test together; the details how the code gets whatever value probably shouldn't matter. If you do automated testing please disregard the above and [edit] your question, explain more, and add a [mcve].

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your reply! I want to do this because my previous teammates wrote some test cases without explanation. My current work is to understand their existing test cases and generate more for the untested parts of our projects. Because there is more than one project on my hand now, I would like to find a more convenient/automatic way to collect log files and understand existing test cases more efficiently. In the current stage, I am not using the automated testing you described. Sorry for the confusion.